# Sending Values from input table with JSON and AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax, json, oracle

I am having a problem in collecting values inserted thru a table and collect them as a JSON array. And after that, sending the array into a JSON for database process. so what i have is this. The table is generated from the database so i am using $posId for identifier how many rows depending on the values from database

```
<tbody>
        <?php 
            $posId = 1;
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($jobnameParse)){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td id='subjob'>".$row['PROJECT_NAME']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['PROJECT_DESC']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' class='startDatePicker' style='margin-top:12px' id='startDate$posId'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' class='endDatePicker' style='margin-top:12px' id='endDate$posId'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' style='margin-top:12px' id='projectWeight$posId'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            $posId++;
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>

<button class="btn btn-large btn-green" onclick="submitJSON();" style="float: right;"><b>SUBMIT JOB TIMESPAN<b></button>
```

and here is the script that is related to that table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jobsetupTable').DataTable();
    $('.startDatePicker').datepicker({dateFormat:"DD, dd-MM-yy"});
    $('.endDatePicker').datepicker({dateFormat:"DD, dd-MM-yy"});
});

var jobTableData;
    jobTableData = storeJobTableData();
    jobTableData = $.toJSON(jobTableData);

function storeJobTableData()
{
    var jobTableData = new Array();
    $('#jobsetupTable tr').each(function(row,tr){
        jobTableData[row]={
            "subJob":$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            "startDate":$(tr).find('td:eq(2)').val(),
            "endDate":$(tr).find('td:eq(3)').val(),
            "subjobWeight":$(tr).find('td:eq(4)').val(),
            "job":'<?php echo $jobValue;?>'
        };
    });
    jobTableData.shift();
    return jobTableData;
}

function submitJSON()
{
    var tableDataValues;
    tableDataValues = $.toJSON(storeJobTableData());

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"processSubmitJobTable.php",
        data:{"tTableData":tableDataValues},
        success: function(msg){
            //Some Return Value
        }
    });
}
```

some how it doesnt collect the .val() input values and i can only get to send the .text() values to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer after hours of trials

```
function storeJobTableData()
    {
        var jobTableData = new Array();
        $('#jobsetupTable tr').each(function(row,tr){
            jobTableData[row]={
                "subJob":$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                "startDate":$(tr).find('td:eq(2)').find('input').val(),
                "endDate":$(tr).find('td:eq(3)').find('input').val(),
                "subjobWeight":$(tr).find('td:eq(4)').find('input').val(),
                "job":'<?php echo $jobValue;?>'
            };
        });
        jobTableData.shift();
        return jobTableData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different way for doing this please take a hidden field for your values like,

```
<input type='hidden' name="startDatePicker[]" class='startDatePicker' style='margin-top:12px' id='startDate$posId'>
```

put this type of hidden fiels in same td for your all the td's and then 
in your jquery instead of doing a data object just serialize your form and post your values as a array at your php controller.
i think this could be short and useful to you.